# Hive TimeZone ID's

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to add timezone for a timestamp in hive and convert back to EST using from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())

I am getting result when I do the following query

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-01 00:25:00.0 Pacific Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z') ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z');
OK
2017-01-01 03:25:00.0 EST
Time taken: 0.126 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

but when I try with other time zone ID's like **US/Pacific, US/Eastern ..**  I am getting null results

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-01 00:25:00.0 US/Eastern', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z') ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z');
OK
NULL
Time taken: 0.119 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-01-01 00:25:00.0 US/Pacific', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z') ,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z');
OK
NULL
```

I can't use short ID's like MST, CST or PST. since these are driven dynamically from other query

My intention here is to convert oracle query

```
cast (FROM_TZ('2017-01-01 00:00:00.0','US/Pacific') at time stamp 'US/Eastern')
```